# Recoger varias excepciones de un try/catch en Java

Tags: java, try-catch

Tengo en mi código un `try/catch`. Dentro del try tengo diferentes validaciones, cada una lanza un tipo de excepción que a su vez extiende de la clase padre "excepción general":

**EXCEPCIÓN GENERAL**

```
public abstract class GeneralException extends Exception {
    public GeneralException (String errorMessage) {
        super(errorMessage);
    }
    public abstract int getError();
}
```

**EJEMPLO DE EXCEPCIÓN HIJA**

```
public static final String ERROR = "String exception";

public IncorrectStrException(String errorMessage) {
    super(ERROR);
}

@Override
public int getError() {
    return ERROR;
}
```

Este es el código donde quiero hacer el `printStackTrace` de todas las excepciones que se lanzan y guardarlas en una lista. Sin embargo, sólo guarda la primera excepción. ¿Sucede esto porque se para la ejecución al momento de lanzarse? Soy nueva con excepciones, he estado buscando y no he encontrado nada.

```
try {
    if (validateNum() && validateStr() && validateDate() && validateName()) {
        generateDoc();
    }
} catch (GeneralException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    exceptionList.add(e);
}
```

**EJEMPLO DE VALIDATEX()**

```
public boolean validateInt(XSSFCell cell) throws IncorrectIntException {
    boolean validation = false;
    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
        validation = true;
    }
    return validation;
}
```

Comment: Según entiendo a partir de lo que nos cuentas, la IncorrectStrException hereda de GeneralException. Debes añadir varios bloques catch siguiendo un orden de la excepción más específica a la más general. En este caso primero un catch para la IncorrectStrException y luego otro para la GeneralException. Así primero intenta capturar la IncorrectStrException  y si no es de ese tipo, prueba con la general. Si sólo pones la general, todas te van a entrar por ese catch ya que es la IncorrectStrException es un tipo de GeneralException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendí que cada catch recoge únicamente una excepción. Por lo tanto, mi solución fue meter try/catch en las funciones que validan para tener así todas las excepciones de cada validate:

```
public boolean validateInt(XSSFCell cell) throws IncorrectIntException {
    boolean validation = false;
    try {
    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
        validation = true;
    }
    return validation;
    } catch (IncorrectIntException e) { 
        e.pintStackTrace();
        exceptionList.add(e);
    }
}
```

También tuve que cambiar esta parte del código y hacer el validate uno a uno:

```
if (validateNum() && validateStr() && validateDate() && validateName()) {
    generateDoc();
```

De esta manera:

```
boolean validate = validateNum() ? true : false;
validate = validateStr() ? true : false;
...

if (validate) { generateDoc(); }
```

No comprendía el flujo que seguía java con respecto al try / catch, ahora veo cuánto me queda por aprender...

Answer (score 2):

Dado que la IncorrectStrException es más concreta que la GeneralException, deberías poner 2 bloques catch, en orden de más concreta a más general.

Sería así:

```
try {
    if (validateNum() && validateStr() && validateDate() && validateName()) {
        generateDoc();
    }
} catch (IncorrectStrException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    exceptionList.add(e);
} catch (GeneralException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    exceptionList.add(e);
}
```

De esta manera, si se produce una excepción, se comprobará primero si es de tipo IncorrectStrException y si no lo es, irá por el de GeneralException. Si sólo pones el catch de GeneralException, todas entrarán en ese catch ya que la IncorrectStrException es hija (más concreta) de GeneralException (general).

Comment: ¿En caso de que haya, por ejemplo, más de un IncorrectStrException, me las guardará todas o sólo la primera?

Comment: Si esto lo estás ejecutando en un bucle, registrará tantas como ocurran. Tal como lo tienes puesto, entiendo que sólo registra una, ya que registrará la del primer validate que falle, y luego continuaría con el resto del código que exista después de los bloques catch

Comment: No es esto lo que estaba preguntando, pero gracias.

Comment: si lo que quieres es capturar todas las posibles excepciones de cada una de la validaciones, tendrías que realizarlas independientemente cada una en un bloque try-catch ya que como lo tienes ahora mismo, si una de ellas falla ya no realiza el resto, por lo tanto sólo tendrás una.

Comment: Exacto, me he respondido a mí misma con la solución, lo que he hecho ha sido añadir un try catch en cada validación. Antes no entendía el flujo de las validaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías manejar las excepciones de la siguiente manera:

```
public void funcionX() {
try {
    //Código a ejecutar
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //Captura la excepción del formato de número...
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    //Captura la excepción de argumentos...
} catch(...)
```

}

Comment: Esto es lo mismo que hacer un catch con GeneralException, ya que todas esas excepciones son hijas de General exception, y en cuanto entra en un catch, sale de la ejecución y no sigue con los demás catch. Yo lo que necesitaba era todos los pintStackTrace de cada excepción, con esta respuesta que me has dado sólo tendría una (la primera que salte). Igualmente gracias.